# Code blocks because it is also trying to generate a circle around it when is a space near

Tags: c#, .net, math, geometry

I am developing a small program, and to generate the coordenates I am using this code:

```
public double[] GenerateNewCircle(int maxSize, int numberOfBalls, double centerx, double centery)
        {

            double[] position = null;

            double angle = 360 / 6;
            double angleRad = DegreeToRadian(incrementAngle);
            position = CalculatePosition(radiusX, radiusY, centerx, centery, angleRad);

            return position;
        }

public double[] CalculatePosition(double radiusX, double radiusY, double centerX, double centerY, double angle)
        {
            double[] position = new double[2];

            position[0] = Math.Cos(angle) * (radiusX + centerX)*1.5;
            position[1] = Math.Sin(angle)  * (radiusY + centerY)*1.5;

            return position;
        }
```

To check if not overlapping or if is in the area I used this

```
bool circleIsAllowed(List<Circle> circles, Circle newCircle)
        {
            if (newCircle.x < 10 || newCircle.x > pictureBox1.Width)
                return false;
            if (newCircle.y < 9 || newCircle.y > pictureBox1.Height)
                return false;

            foreach (Circle it in circles)
            {
                double aX = Math.Pow(it.x - newCircle.x, 2);
                double aY = Math.Pow(it.y - newCircle.y, 2);
                double Dif = Math.Abs(aX - aY);
                double ra1 = it.r / 2;
                double ra2 = it.r / 2;

                double raDif = Math.Pow(ra1 + ra2, 2);
                if ((raDif + 1) > Dif) return false;             
            }
            return true; // no existing circle overlaps
        }
```

I have two problems right now

1. It blocks because is also trying to generate a circle around it, when is a space near.
2. How can I increase the distance between the circles? They are too close.

This circles is to draw around a circle (around it)

This is the image:

[image]

Comment: Slightly off topic, but if your functions returned a 'Point' instead of a double[] the API would be easier to understand. And maybe GenerateNewCircle would be better called something like CalculateCircleCenter. And why does the function GenerateNewCircle have a numberOfBalls parameter (it isn't used). And in the same method you use local variables radiusX and radiousY, which don't exist!

Comment: It might be an idea to include a picture of what it does now (show us what's wrong), and what you're trying to achieve. I'm not clear after reading your question several times.

Comment: that was from testing testing and testing, and i forget to delete those variables :P... i dont return a point, because the main goal of this project is only to get the coordenates so is why returned tin double[]

Comment: just add a image of the program. in the center, those balls are too much close, i want to make a little more distance between them

Comment: One problem is the distance between the balls, I want to add a little more, the other is sometimes is trying to insert a ball, and the programs blocks, because is in a loop trying to create a ball and is overlapping, when are a free are near.

Comment: How can a circle have different X and Y radii?

Comment: dont understand lucero, what you mean? if a radio of circle can be bigger? , no is all the same (80)

Comment: just add my entire code, if you wanna see,

Comment: What @lucero means is that a circle always has the same radius everywhere. I "circle" with different radii is called "Ellipse".

Comment: ahh ok, is in a variable because is to increase and decrease the size of the circles

Comment: @Luis, it's fine to have the radius in a variable, you bu have two: `radiusX` and `radiusY` which made me wonder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is mistake in second code block. Try this:

```
double aX = Math.Pow(it.x - newCircle.x, 2);
double aY = Math.Pow(it.y - newCircle.y, 2);
double distance = Math.Pow(aX + aY, 0.5); // distance between circles centers

double ra1 = it.r / 2;
double ra2 = it.r / 2;
// is it.r diameter? if so, then ok, else div by 2 is useless

double circlesDistance = 10; // distance between circles (not centers)

if (distance < ra1 + ra2 + circlesDistance)
{
    return false;
}
```

Comment: hi, its better now tks, but for example if i click near the right limit or if I set the circles distace to 40 it 'explode' and says that a number is too small or too big :S. when have some area to draw. what can be wrong?

Comment: Please, explain clearer your problem. Where is 'explode' take place? Number of *what* is too small or too big?

Comment: i gonna add myu project so you can see it better. And tks again

Answer (score 1):

To compute the distance between two circle centers, you should apply the [Pythagorean Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagoras#Pythagorean_theorem):

> a<sup>2</sup> + b<sup>2</sup> = c<sup>2</sup>.

This works perfectly if we have circles (with ellipses you'd have to compute their radius along the connection between their centres which would involve some sinus and cosinus computations).

```
double aX = Math.Pow(it.x - newCircle.x, 2);
double aY = Math.Pow(it.y - newCircle.y, 2);
if ((aX + aY) <= Math.Pow(it.r + newCircle.r, 2)) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: hi lucero, just tried and happend the same as  DotNET Ninja :S, cant generate more than 6 balls and then say the number is too small or to big (number of the coordenate)

Comment: @Luis, this problem of yours is not related to this piece of code. I posted it because this is a concise and fast way of correctly checking the intersection of two circles. And if you want to have a minimal distance between two circles, just add it to the `it.r + newCircle.r` expression.